# Post to a nested JSON object using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, http, nested

I have a form that calls out to an external api using $http.post.  It works, however, I now need to add input fields for Address, City, State and Zip.  However the json for the address is nested and I've tried everything to access it but could not.  The json looks like this now.  And I need to post the Address properties to my form now.

```
{

"FirstName": "string",

"LastName": "string",

 "Address": {

    "Address1": "string",

    "Address2": "string",

    "City": "string",

    "PostalCode": "string",

    "Country": "string",

    "State": "string",
}
```

**The HTML code:**

```
<form novalidate="" role="form" name="prizeLogicForm" id="prizeForm" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-email">
            <h1 class="heading-sub-a-xl" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Entry Form</h1>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : prizeLogicForm.FirstName.$invalid &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.FirstName.$dirty}">
                <label for="FirstName" class="align-form required">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" ng-model="FirstName" ng-required="true" required="required">
                <span class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="prizeLogicForm.FirstName.$error.required &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.FirstName.$dirty">First Name is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : prizeLogicForm.LastName.$invalid &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.LastName.$dirty}">
                <label for="Lastname" class="align-form required">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="LastName" name="LastName" ng-model="LastName" ng-required="true" required="required">
                <span class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="prizeLogicForm.LastName.$error.required &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.LastName.$dirty">Last Name is required.</span>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : prizeLogicForm.Address1.$invalid &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.Address1.$dirty}">
                <label for="Lastname" class="align-form required">Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="Address1" name="Address1" ng-model="Address1" ng-required="true" required="required">
                <span class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="prizeLogicForm.Address1.$error.required &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.Address1.$dirty">Address is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : prizeLogicForm.City.$invalid &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.City.$dirty}">
                <label for="City" class="align-form required">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="City" name="City" ng-model="City" ng-required="true" required="required">
                <span class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="prizeLogicForm.City.$error.required &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.City.$dirty">City is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : prizeLogicForm.State.$invalid &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.State.$dirty}">
                <label for="State" class="align-form required">State</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="State" name="State" ng-model="State" ng-required="true" required="required">
                <span class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="prizeLogicForm.State.$error.required &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.State.$dirty">State is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : prizeLogicForm.Zip.$invalid &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.Zip.$dirty}">
                <label for="State" class="align-form required">Zip</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="Zip" name="Zip" ng-model="Zip" ng-required="true" required="required">
                <span class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="prizeLogicForm.Zip.$error.required &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.Zip.$dirty">Zip is required.</span>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : prizeLogicForm.Phone.$invalid &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.Phone.$dirty}">
                <label for="phone" class="align-form required">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="Phone" name="Phone" ng-model="Phone" ng-required="true" required="required">
                <span class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="prizeLogicForm.Phone.$error.required &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.Phone.$dirty">Phone is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : prizeLogicForm.Email.$invalid &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.Email.$dirty}">
                <label for="email" class="align-form required">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="Email" name="Email" ng-model="Email" ng-required="true" required="required">
                <span class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="prizeLogicForm.Email.$error.required &amp;&amp; prizeLogicForm.Email.$dirty">Email is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="AgreeToRules" ng-required="true" class="align-form required ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="required"> <strong>I have read and agree to be bound by the Official Rules and am 21 years of age or older. <span style="color: #d13a17;">*</span></strong>
                </label>
            </div>
            <!--Remember to add newsletter option, its not added currently to the service.-->
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="OptIn" ng-required="false" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required"> I would like to receive the Texas Tourism email newsletter and I understand that I may <a href="http://traveltex.us4.list-manage1.com/unsubscribe?u=e573ec85eee8fb1a7e9b35f86&amp;id=592bc032c8" target="_blank">unsubscribe</a> at any time. See our <a href="https://www.traveltexas.com/privacy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a> for more details.
                </label>
            </div>

            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="prizeLogicForm.$invalid" value="Submit" ng-click="postdata(FirstName, LastName, AgreeToRules, OptIn, Phone, Email)" disabled="disabled"> <br><br>
            <!--<input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-bottom" value="Submit" ng-disabled="!checked" data-ng-click="postdata(FirstName, LastName, AgreeToRules, OptIn, Phone, Email)" /> <br /><br />-->

        </form>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.IsSuccessVisible = false;
    $scope.IsStatusVisible = false; // Hide form on init
    $scope.IsFormVisible = true; // Show form on init
    $scope.FirstName = null;
    $scope.LastName = null;
    $scope.Address1 = null;
    $scope.City = null;
    $scope.PostalCode = null;
    $scope.State = null;
    $scope.AgreeToRules = false;
    $scope.OptIn = false;
    $scope.Phone = null;
    $scope.Email = null;
    $scope.postdata = function (

        FirstName,
        LastName,
        Address1,
        City,
        PostalCode,
        State,
        AgreeToRules,
        OptIn,
        Phone,
        Email
        ) {
        var data = {
            FirstName: FirstName,
            LastName: LastName,
            Address1: Address1,
            City: City,
            PostalCode: PostalCode,
            State: State,
            AgreeToRules: AgreeToRules,
            OptIn: OptIn,
            Phone: Phone,
            Email: Email
        };
        //Call the services
      $http.post('externalAPIurlhere',

            JSON.stringify(data)).then(function (response) {

                console.log("Success Status: ", response.data);
                $scope.msg = response.data.UserGuid;

                $scope.IsFormVisible = false;  //Hide form
                $scope.IsSuccessVisible = true; //Show form



            }, function (response) {
                console.log("Failure Status: ", response.data);

                $scope.msg = response.data.Message;

                if ($scope.msg === 'Model is invalid') {
                    $scope.msg = 'Invalid phone number. Try Again!';
                    console.log('Message Updated');
                };
                $scope.statusval = response.status;
                $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
                $scope.headers = response.headers();
                $scope.IsFormVisible = false;  //Hide form
                $scope.IsStatusVisible = true; //Show form

            });
```

Comment: Show me the part where you assign JSON data to `$scope` variables.

Comment: @Hoa I assign it here $scope.msg.data using stringify(data) however I removed the external $http.post url for security reasons.

Comment: There is no need to stringify the data as the `$http.post` service automatically stringifies JavaScript objects.

Comment: The `ng-model` directive works with object properties, e.g. `ng-model="data.FirstName"`, `ng-model="data.address.address1`, etc.. Then there is no need to copy a list of individual items to a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that in order to fix the issue, I had to setup the var data = {..} sections object notation literally the same way the JSON was layed out.  This allowed me to post to Address1, City, PostalCode and State successfully.  However $scope.postdata function code needed to reference all sub properties like so:

```
$scope.postdata = function (
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        AgreeToRules,
        OptIn,
        Phone,
        OtherOptIn,
        Email,
        **Address1**,
        **City**,
        **PostalCode**,
        **State**
        )
```

So it should have been like this:

```
var data = {
            FirstName: FirstName,
            LastName: LastName,
            AgreeToRules: AgreeToRules,
            OptIn: OptIn,
            Phone: Phone,
            OtherOptIn: OtherOptIn,
            Email: Email,
            **Address**: {
                **Address1**: **Address1**,
                **City**: **City**,
                **PostalCode**: **PostalCode**,
                **State**: **State**
            }
```

I hope this helps anyone who wants to post to a form using an external API.